# How to correctly place objects in the Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am slowly moving towards developing the client side using Bootstrap. I can't figure out in any way why the proportions of the authorization form are deformed... I just want to place the logo and the authorization form in the same horizontal plane. Tell me how to do it better, or point me in the right direction.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yn3i.png).

The authorization form itself:

```
{{-- Authorization.blade.php --}}
@extends('Pattern.TemplateAR')

@section('title', 'Авторизация')

@section('content')
<div class="Block-TemplatesAR">
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class = "row justify-content-md-left">
    <div class = "col-md-6">
    <img src   = "{{ asset('images/Логотип.png') }}" alt = "Логотип" class = "img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="{{ url('/authenticate') }}" method="post" class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-5 bg-white">
                <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Авторизация</h1>
                @csrf

                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com" autocomplete="email" required>
                    <label for="email">Электронная почта</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <label for="password">Пароль</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check text-start my-4">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="flexCheckDefault" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Выберите, чтобы сохранить данные учетной записи для быстрого входа">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Запомнить сессию</label>
                </div>

                <button class="w-100 btn-custom-size" type="submit">Авторизироваться</button>
                <hr class="my-3"> 
                
                <div class="text-center">
                    <small><a href="{{ route('registration') }}" class="text-decoration-none">Зарегистрироваться</a></small>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The template form itself with Bootstrap enabled:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('images/logo.ico') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/TemplatesAR.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.7.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>@yield('title', '')</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{-- Встраиваемая логика вне шаблона --}}
    @yield('content')

    {{-- Инициализация всплывающих служебных сообщений --}}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried using the official Bootstrap documentation, but I can't find an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Электронная почта
    @error('email')
        {{ $message }}
    @enderror


    
    Пароль
    @error('password')
        {{ $message }}
    @enderror

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).